# How to specify route options to specific controllers in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to suppress the controller from the route, and it worked fine using  this:

```
         routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HomePages",
            url: "{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

The problem is when doing the same for a different controller like "Account", the first option only will take effect :

```
            routes.MapRoute(
     name: "LoginRoute",
     url: "{action}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
     );
```

My objective is to hide the controller from the route, so i can directly access mysite.com/login and mysite.com/index, how to achieve that when login is under Account controller and index is under Home controller?

How to specify the second option for the Account actions, and keep the first for the Home actions?

Comment: Think what you want to achieve first - currently both match exactly the same set of Urls and first match will win...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I want to hide the controller from the route, so i can directly access mysite.com/login and mysite.com/index how to achieve that login is under `Account` controller and index is under `Home` controller?

Comment: `url: "Login",  defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }` - if you don't need to map all actions (make sure more specific routes are mentioned first).

Comment: Is there any way to map on Controller level not only action level, Say i have many actions under Account and many more under Home, Should i map it on action level one by one? In other words, One route option for all actions under one controller and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using the Routing attributes e.g:

```
[Route("{getId:int}")]
public ActionResult Show(int getId) { ... }
```

you can use this in conjunction with the old way of routing. You do need to explicitly set this functionality in your config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

I have found the routing Attributes makes it very easy to set good routes on my controller methods. This also bleeds into web api and RESTFul stuff as well.